# What the following line of code with malloc does?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I have the following implementation to mirror the binary tree.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* A binary tree node has data, pointer to left child
   and a pointer to right child */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
   given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int data)

{
  struct node* node = (struct node*)
                       malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node->data = data;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;

  return(node);
}


/* Change a tree so that the roles of the  left and
    right pointers are swapped at every node.

 So the tree...
       4
      / \
     2   5
    / \
   1   3

 is changed to...
       4
      / \
     5   2
        / \
       3   1
*/
void mirror(struct node* node)
{
  if (node==NULL)
    return; 
  else
  {
    struct node* temp;

    /* do the subtrees */
    mirror(node->left);
    mirror(node->right);

    /* swap the pointers in this node */
    temp        = node->left;
    node->left  = node->right;
    node->right = temp;
  }
}


/* Helper function to test mirror(). Given a binary
   search tree, print out its data elements in
   increasing sorted order.*/
void inOrder(struct node* node)
{
  if (node == NULL)
    return;

  inOrder(node->left);
  printf("%d ", node->data);

  inOrder(node->right);
} 


/* Driver program to test mirror() */
int main()
{
  struct node *root = newNode(1);
  root->left        = newNode(2);
  root->right       = newNode(3);
  root->left->left  = newNode(4);
  root->left->right = newNode(5);

  /* Print inorder traversal of the input tree */
  printf("\n Inorder traversal of the constructed tree is \n");
  inOrder(root);

  /* Convert tree to its mirror */
  mirror(root);

  /* Print inorder traversal of the mirror tree */
  printf("\n Inorder traversal of the mirror tree is \n"); 
  inOrder(root);

  getchar();
  return 0; 
}
```

I am talking about the following line:

```
  struct node* node = (struct node*)
                       malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

I have intermediate knowledge of c/c++ but I am quite afraid of pointers. Even after several tries I have never been able to get pointers. I avoid them as far as possible but when come to implementing data structures like trees there is no other options. Why are we using malloc and sizeof here? Also why are we casting (struct node*)?

Comment: check the answer. If you find anything missing, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all casting when using malloc in C is not necessary. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

You are malloc-ing because you are allocating heap memory of the size of a node struct. You see in C you have to keep in mind where all the variables are stored. Namely the `stack` and `heap` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap))

Inside a function your variables are termed **local variables**, which is stored in the `stack`. Once you leave the function that variables in the stack are cleared.

To be able to reference or use local variables outside of the function you have to allocate memory in the `heap`, which is what you are doing here. You are allocating memory in the heap so that you can reuse the same variable in other functions as well.

In summary:

- **Variables within a function** are local to the function, hence the term **local variable**
- **For other functions to access the local variable**, you have to **allocate memory in the heap to share** that variable with other functions.

To give you an example why, consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *some_string_func()
{
    char some_str[13]; /* 12 chars (for "Hello World!") + 1 null '\0' char */

    strcpy(some_str, "Hello World!");

    return some_str;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", some_string_func());
    return 0;
}
```

Its pretty simple, `main` is simply calling a function `some_str_func` which returns a local variable `some_str`, compiling the above code would work, but not without warnings:

```
test.c: In function ‘some_string_func’:
test.c:11:9: warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
```

Although it compiles note that `some_str` in `some_str_func()` is **returning a local variable** to the function (i.e. in the function's stack). Since the stack is cleared once you leave the function `some_str_func()`, in `main()` it would **not be possible** to get the contents of `some_str` which is "Hello World".

If you attempt to run it you get:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out

$
```

It prints nothing, cause it cannot access `some_str`. To remedy it you allocate some memory space for the string "Hello World" instead. like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *some_string_func()
{
    char *some_str;

    /* allocate 12 chars (for "Hello World!") + 1 null '\0' char */
    some_str = calloc(13, sizeof(char));

    strcpy(some_str, "Hello World!");

    return some_str;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = some_string_func();
    printf("%s\n", str);

    free(str);  /* remember to free the allocated memory */
    return 0;
}
```

Now when you compile and run it, you get:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
Hello World!
$
```

If you are having a hard time understanding C, I know many people find "The C Programming Language" by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie a really good reference, however a more modern and graphical (even fun to read! seriously) book is **[Head First C](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920015482.do)** By David and Dawn Griffiths, they explain many important C concepts such as Heap and Stack, difference between dynamic and static C libraries, why using Makefiles is a good idea, how does Make work, and many more concepts not previously explained in common C books, definitely worth a look.

Another good online resource is Zed Shaws **[Learn C the Hard way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/)**, in which he provides good code examples and notes.

Comment: And how is it different than when we use new in C++ or Java?

Comment: @user1425223 The result of `malloc` is a pointer to an uninitialized memory. unlike `new`. you can say that `new T(args)` ~= `malloc(sizeof(T))` + `T(args)`.

Comment: It would be worthwhile to mention that all this about "the heap" and "the stack" is not something mentioned in the Standard. For example, on some embedded platforms, there's no heap, and `malloc()` simplu returns a pointer to "some memory that is not the stack" (see the implementation of `malloc()` in the AVR-libc, for instance).

Comment: @H2CO3 Something like `freestore`.Right catch

Comment: @H2CO3 "heap" and "stack" is the common terminology, and it is also accurate for most implementations and developers. Nothing wrong with it. It's like the "NULL is address 0x0".

Comment: @Elazar I didn't say it's not common. I said it's not universal and not in the standard. The formal description of a C implementation has no notion of a "stack" or a "heap" or whatever. Yes, those are popular kinds of implementation, but as I just mentioned, there are counter-examples. Also, `NULL` need not be the address 0x0, although it generally is. Go ask some old riders around here, they will enumerate for you some of the machines they've worked with on which `NULL` wasn't numeric zero.

Comment: But newcomers need not be concerned with details of standard/formal terminology. (And I know about the NULL thing - that's why I gave it as an example: It is *rare*).

Comment: @user1425223 do yo have any further questions? If not please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: Chutsu Small problem if you uses `strcpy()` you don't need to terminate string explicitly so remove `some_str[12] = '\0'; /* remember to null terminate */` from code. Anyways good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Read: [`void *malloc(size_t size);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

> The `malloc()` function allocates `size` bytes and returns a pointer to
>          the allocated memory.  The memory is not initialized.  If size is 0,
>          then `malloc()` returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can
>          later be successfully passed to `free()`.

Accordingly, in

```
struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  //                                     ^----size---------^
```

you are allocating memory chunk of `size = sizeof naode` bytes and address return from malloc stored in `node`pointer.

**Note** You have mistake variable name shouldn't be `node` as it is struct name. You can! but Not good practice, though. Also, `sizeof(*pointer)` is preferred over `sizeof(Type)` in case the type is ever changed

Side note: It is safe to avoid not to cast return address by malloc and calloc function. read: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

So <del>correct</del> preferable form of above statement is:

```
struct node* nd = malloc(sizeof *nd);
  //                     ^----size-^
```

Two rectifications: (1) Remove typecast and (2) change variable name to `nd`.

Comment: "You have mistake variable name can't be node as it is struct name." - he can. Not good practice, though. Also, `sizeof(*pointer)` is preferred over `sizeof(Type)` in case the type is ever changed.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is it ?? ... interesting. I again copy from you :) Thanks!

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks you very much H2co3 man. Next it shouldn't be correct in C++ because in C++ we can use structure name without struct keyword .Am I correct?

Comment: @H2CO3 Got it in C++ class namespace and variable name space are different. Excellent man!

Comment: @Elazar sorry I didn't try I learned from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858) please check and suggest rectification.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: In C++, there's no implicit conversion from `void*` to `object_type*`, so a cast would be needed. But it's rarely a good idea to call `malloc` in C++; either use `new` or some container class that handles allocation for you.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes this I understood. My confusion is in [this working code](http://ideone.com/Dkrh2p) because in C++ we don't need to use struct after declaration So suppose if I have same `struct ABC {};` then I can simply declare `ABC a;` no need to use struct (but use in C) Now how `ABC ABC;` become correct "Does C++ use different namespaces for variables and types **?**" I know many function with same names are possible (overloading) with different signature compiler change their name.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `sizeof`-**

`sizeof`(**T**) will tell the number of bytes required to store a variable of type **T**

**Using `malloc`-**

Malloc allocates memory dynamically, that is, at the runtime (when your program is actually being executed by CPU and its in memory). We use this mostly when we are not sure about the amount of memory which is required at runtime. So we dynamically allocate it at runtime using `malloc`.

**Using (`struct node*`)-**

`Malloc` returns a pointer to a block of memory with the amount of space that you asked for (in its parameters). This space is just some space in memory. Thus this pointer has no type associated with it. We cast this pointer to (`struct node*`) because it will let the machine know that the variables of type (`struct node`) are going to be saved in this memory.

Comment: Thank you! The using of (struct node*) was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
void* malloc (size_t size);
```

> Allocate memory block
>
> Allocates a block of size bytes of memory, returning a pointer to the
>   beginning of the block. The content of the newly allocated block of
>   memory is not initialized, remaining with indeterminate values. If
>   size is zero, the return value depends on the particular library
>   implementation (it may or may not be a null pointer), but the returned
>   pointer shall not be dereferenced.

And do not cast the result of `malloc`.

You also need to free this memory:

```
void free (void* ptr);
```

> Deallocate memory block
>
> A block of memory previously allocated by a call to malloc, calloc or
>   realloc is deallocated, making it available again for further
>   allocations.

Answer (score 0):

you use malloc to typically let pointers have something to point to.

a pointer is just like a street address and the building that stands on the address is constructed by malloc -- or at least the size needed to build the building -- what you build there is up to you.

in your example each node in the tree is a number of bytes allocated with malloc, the size of the node is the number of bytes needed to hold all the contents of the node.

the binary tree will get each of its nodes allocated with malloc, where in memory is irrelevant and that maybe is the thing that is a bit tricky to understand with malloc and pointers. as long as there are pointers to those locations all is well.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

alocates enough space to hold a `node` structure